# If A is an open set does A the complement of A have to be closed? I know the opossite is true by definition, is this?

Tags: general-topology

Quick question if $A \subset X$, $A$ open in $X$, does $X \setminus A$ absolutely have to be closed ?

Comment: A set is closed if its complement is open.

Comment: I guess you mean $X\setminus A$ or $X-A$ instead of $X/A$ which often denotes the quotient space.

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $X\setminus (X\setminus A) = A $.